# Probabilistic stacking of blocks

Tags: homework-and-exercises, probability, geometry, equilibrium

This is a variation on [the stacking problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block-stacking_problem).
A *block* is a 1D object of length *L* and uniformly distributed mass. (with some negligible thickness).
A *stack* of size *n* is a series of *n* blocks placed flat one **over** the other(i.e. their lengths are parallel).
A *stable* stack is one that doesn't topple under constant gravity.
A *monolayer* stack is where at most $1$ block is **immediately** above another block.

We are interested in finding the probability that a monolayer stack constructed ground-up from $n$ blocks is stable.
The stack is constructed probabilistically as follows:

1. Place the first block.(say with its left edge at $0$)
2. The next block is placed randomly such that it touches the block immediately before, at least somewhere, equally probably i.e. its left edge is in $(-L,L)$,equally probably. The probability of the block landing outside is taken $0$. (say its left edge is at $-L<x_2<L$ and nowhere else)
3. Place the third block immediately above the second with the same probability distribution. (i.e its left edge $x_3$ can land anywhere in $(x_2-L,x_2+L)$ and nowhere else)
4. and so on till the *n*-th block.

Of course most such random stacks topple. Question is , **what is the probability $p(n)$ that the stack stays stable during construction**?

[image: example stacks]

---

### So far...

I have figured out the following constriants
1. $\forall m \ge2$, $x_{m-1}-L<x_m<x_{m-1}+L$ (placement region) and
2. $\forall m \ge1$,$x_m-L/2<Average[x_{m+1},x_{m+2},...x_n]<x_m+L/2$

(2) is motivated by the fact that placing a block shouldn't destabilise the stack below. For this we calculate the COM of the $block_n$, then $block_n+block_{n-1}$ and so on till all such sub-stacks are found to be stable
3. $p(n)=\frac{1}{2^{n-1}} \frac ab$ for some positive rational $\frac ab \lt 1$ (from numerical analysis)

Calulating phase space volume subject to above constraints as a function of $n$ seems difficult.
Am I missing some physics which would make the calculation straightforward?
So far I have found(with $L=1$) (mc denotes via monte-carlo),
$$
\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline n & p(n) \\ \hline 1 & 1 \\ \hline 2 & 1/2 \\ \hline 3 & 7/32 (mc:0.218) \\ \hline 4 & 107/1152 (mc:0.0928) \\ \hline 5 & 2849/73728 (mc:  0.0385\pm 0.0004) \\ \hline 6 & mc: 0.0156\pm0.003\\ \hline \end{array}
$$

Comment: plz move to math se if needed

Comment: Is your high value for $p(4)$ a typo? What does *frommc* mean?

Comment: @G.Smith had a typo before in the mc value(was 0.926)..its correct now

Comment: Where did the exact fractions come from?

Comment: till p(3) by hand, rest mathematica

Comment: In my opinion this question should be closed as it reads like a homework-like/"check my work" question.

Comment: @AaronStevens 1. It isn't  a hw. problem because I haven't come across it as such 2. I am asking if there is an answer available in terms of n--this requires a simplifying foresight which is the point of the question. Without it, only brute force solving can be used for a given n 3. No need to check anything, the "So far..." part of the question is just to show the effort put in, well, so far, in line with the style of asking se questions and to motivate anyone towards finding a unifying pattern..

Comment: Essentially the same question was asked on Math StackExchange a few years ago https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/606300/height-of-domino-tower

Answer (score 0):

A block is sits on top of the block below if its center is lower the bottom block. The odds of that are 1/2.

Each block in the stack, except the bottom has a 1/2 chance of spoiling the stable stack. The odds are $2^{-(n-1)}$.

Comment: *center is lower* its a vertical stacking please clarify

Comment: *has a 1/2 chance of spoiling...* not necessarily as even if the block maybe stable wrt the one immediately beneth, it may not be wrt to the one further below

Comment: at this point, the $2^{-(n-1)}$ doesn't seem to match the monte carlo or $p(3)$

Comment: "if its center is lower the bottom block" Do you mean "over the bottom block?